# CakePHP validation on recordset

Tags: validation, cakephp, model

I am trying to read all the records form the database, pass them through the validate() function to test for validation before I send them off to a 3rd party API. I am getting validated data even though I deliberately create invalid entries:

I build a small test case:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class ValidatetestsController extends AppController {

    public function test() {
        $this->Validatetest->set(array('clientname' => 'tooshort'));

        if ($this->Validatetest->validates()) {
            return('Data Validated');
        } else {
            return('Data Not Validated');
        }
    }

    public function testfails() {
        $this->Validatetest->set($this->Validatetest->find('all'));

        if ($this->Validatetest->validates()) {
            return('Data Validated');
        } else {
            return('Data Not Validated');
        }
    }
}
```

My simple test table looks like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `validatetests`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `validatetests` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `clientname` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `validatetests` (`id`, `clientname`) VALUES
    (2, 'tooshort');
```

When I call

- `validatetests/test` - it works 100% in that is does not validate
- `validatetests/testfails` - it fails in that validates when the value is too short

The difference is the structure of the data array!

WORKS: (Data Not Validated)

```
Array([Validatetest] => Array([clientname] => tooshort))
```

DOES NOT WORK: (Data Validated)

```
Array([Validatetest] => Array([0] => Array([Validatetest] => Array([id] => 2[clientname] => tooshort))))
```

Cookbook (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-all) says the structure is correct but that structure does not get validated.

Please help

Comment: I don't think you can validate an array of record (i.e., `$this->Validatetest->set($this->Validatetest->find('all'));` )? Did you read [how to validate from the controller](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html) or any examples of more than 1 record being validated?  You should dig around the source code. Check out if [validateMany](http://api.cakephp.org/2.6/source-class-Model.html#2379) can be used.